Book recommendations for a coordinate free approach on multivariate real analysis
I'm taking a course on multivariate real analysis this semester (the topics covered in the course are close to the topics in Analysis on Manifolds by James Munkres),
The course is limited to the spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard euclidean distance. However I recently grew interested in coordinate free linear algebra and picked up Werner Greub books on Linear Algebra and Multilinear algebra (didn't get to the multilinear algebra book yet), are there any recommendations for books on the subject that talks about functions between abstract vector spaces (or inner product spaces) using a coordinate free approach?
A few more points:

I don't know any topology or measure theory, the courses I took on single variable real analysis were limited to functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (metric spaces were not introduced, but I'm fine with books that introduce concepts from said fields aslong as they do not assume prior knowledge)

I'm looking for rigorous books, I'm comfortable with reading and writing proofs and I'm fine with definition, theorem, proof kind of books but books with some motivation, interesting examples and problems are preferred aslong as the definitions and proofs don't become too chatty.

I prefer books that do not assume prior knowledge of multivariate analysis or multivariable calculus.



Have you tried searching for books like this? What books did you find and why weren't they sufficient? Most advanced undergraduate and graduate texts on analysis are coordinate free, when possible.

Doing it coordinate free might also not be ideal for a first read if you want to learn to actually compute things explicitly (which you often want to do in a first course)

Dieudonne's Foundations of Modern Analysis is a classic for this.

Loomis and Sternberg, Henri Cartan.

There are two different directions and it’s not clear what way you mean. If you want to do analysis on an abstract vector space, then you want to study Banach and Hilbert spaces. Here the most interesting aspect is infinite dimensional spaces. This direction is known as functional analysis. The other is studying nonlinear abstract spaces, commonly known as manifolds. Munkres does this by working with submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is a good way to start. If you want abstract manifolds from the start, Tu’s book is good. But you’ll always using coordinates. It’s unavoidable.

I would recommend the book by Jean Dieudonné - Foundations of Modern Analysis. In particular chapters V to VIII.
Advantages:

It is rigorous.
It generally covers Banach spaces, with a coordinate-free approach, which I like when possible—using the coordinates hides many profound results.
You have several good problems/exercises at the end of each chapter (without solutions though).

Drawback:

It is pretty old and the way to manage proof is sometimes different nowadays.
Some young students are surprised / not at ease with the old typography of the book!


What do you mean by the way to manage proof is different?

@peek-a-boo Mainly, I mean that details may be omitted, and that you may have to fill them in. That is a rather subjective statement though.
